# Redirect search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, elasticsearch

I've followed [this tuto](http://www.sitepoint.com/full-text-search-rails-elasticsearch/) to make a search form in my app.
It works well but it doesn't do exactly what I want

At the moment, I've to go to /search to see my result but I want that when a search is made, everywhere in my app, it's redirect on /search and the results are displayed.

My search controller :

```
def search
 if params[:q].nil?
  @idees = []
 else
  @idees = Idee.search params[:q]
 end
end
```

My search form view

```
<%= form_for search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
<p>
 <%= f.label "Search for" %>
 <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
 <%= submit_tag "Go", name: nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

And my route :

```
get '/search', to: 'search#search'
```

It has to be a problem with my route but I don't know how to do this

Comment: It will already do that. Just put the form on any view you wish to have search functionality (or in the layout if you want it on every view) and upon submitting you will be taken to the search results page

Comment: The search form is already in my layout app. But if I'm in contact page and I want to search article, when I submit the research I get /contact?utf8=✓&q=test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your form as:

```
<%= form_for :search, url: search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
```

You may need to update you `search` action too to support nested params.